# Update ActionBar title of Android Activity from a React Native Fragment back press

Tags: android, react-native

I have a React Native feature embedded inside an Android Application. I need to update the ActionBar of Android Activity from the React Native Screen. I have got this working by using a Bridge and calling the bridge from js file.

I am facing one issue for some time now, if I navigate from one React Native Screen to another and the Action bar title is updated correctly, but if I use the "**back button**" to go back to the previous screen, it does not update the action bar title. Here is the code snippet:

**Bridge.java**

```
@ReactMethod
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    final String actionBarTitle = title;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
            activity.setTitle(actionBarTitle);
        }
    });
}
```

**ReactScreen.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
    NativeModules.ActivityStarter.setActionBarTitle(this.props.item.defectType)
}
```

I have tried using componentWillReceiveProps() as well, but it doesn't seem to get a callback when using the back button in Android.

Also, I am using StackNavigator from react-navigation, so it provides BackHandler which overrides the back button press, but it doesn't seem to be a right solution, I think one of the lifecycle methods should get a callback on back press.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting up the ActionBar title in componentDidMount(), now I am using onNavigationStateChange() from the Navigator, and detecting the current Screen by iterating through states.

App.js

```
const App = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Navigator
            onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
                if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                    const prevScreen = this.findRouteNameFromNavigatorState(prevState);
                    const currentScreen = this.findRouteNameFromNavigatorState(currentState);
                    if (prevScreen !== currentScreen) {
                        this.setActionBarTitle(currentState, currentScreen);
                    }
                }
            }}
        />
    </Provider>
);

findRouteNameFromNavigatorState = (state) => {
    const route = this.getRoute(state);
    if (route !== undefined)
        return route.routeName;
};
```

Ref: [pensierinmusica Answer](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/962)